# Reverse for 'dome_view' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dome2/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: django, forms, api, external, patch

I have try to send request to external API in order to perform PATCH method.
I have a view defined as below:
def dome_view(request, id):
......

I need id in order to pass it to form action and make necessary update on other endpoint which is external.My url pattern is like that path('dome2/int:id/', views.dome_view, name='dome_view'),

When I put id to my form action like below, i got an error "Reverse for 'dome_view' with no arguments not found. "

**form action="{% url 'dome_view' id %}"**

But when i put the exact id that i want to update, then PATCH method succeded.
**For example: form action="{% url 'dome_view' 5 %}" method="post">**

How can i achieve to successfully send PATCH request without specifiying exact id every time to form action?
I just want to do it like <**form action="{% url 'dome_view' id %}"** method="post"

What am i missing?

My python view

```
def dome_view(request, id):
     filled_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
     if request.method == 'POST':
        if filled_form.is_valid():
            ''' Begin reCAPTCHA validation '''
            recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
            url = '<google_captchurl>'
            values = {
               'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
               'response': recaptcha_response
            }
            data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode()
            req =  urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            result = json.loads(response.read().decode())
            ''' End reCAPTCHA validation '''
            if result['success']:
                      
                url = "<here_api_url_for_auth>"
                requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)
                payload={}
                headers = {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                   'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxx'
                }
                        
                response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
                tok=response.json().get('response')['token']
                p_url = "<here_my_api_url_for_patch>"
                p_url += str(id)
                  payload = json.dumps({
                   "fieldData": {
                
                   "yas": filled_form.cleaned_data['yas']
                  }
                })
                headers = {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                   'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ tok
                }                          
                
                response = requests.request("PATCH", p_url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
                if response.status_code == 200:
           
                   return HttpResponseRedirect("/thank-you")
                else:
                   do smth
            else:
               do smth
    else:
         form = ContactForm()
         return render(request, 'my_forms/dome2.html', {'contactform':form})
```

Thanks

Comment: can we see your function in the views?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding id on render request part:
Before

```
else:
    form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'my_forms/dome2.html', {'contactform':form})
```

After

```
else:
    form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'my_forms/dome2.html', {'contactform':form, 'id':id})
```

And on my html template i added id also

BEfore:

```
<form action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="post">
```

After:

```
<form action="{% url 'contact' id %}" method="post">
```

Regards